# Function search in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, search, tensorflow

I have a csv file about insurance attribute and statistics value. There is a function in Tensorflow that inputs the attributes returns the respective values?

For example if i have attributes about: id, age and sex. There is a function that return the record that contain the value?

Answer (score 1):

Look at tensorflow feature columns, which are a useful library to extract and manipulate this kind of data.

Comment: And in Python there is a function that do it?

Comment: Look at the documentation for tensorflow feature columns and tensorflow csv parsing